# EF многие-ко-многим: как правильно добавить поле в связующую таблицу?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть модели:

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Corporation> Corporations { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        Corporations = new List<Corporation>();
    }
}


class Corporation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Corporation()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

При создании связи Many-To-Many в базе данных создаётся связующая таблица вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно добавить поле `WorkTime`. Что я делаю:

1. Добавляю поле в базе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Создаю модель

   ```
   class EmployeeCorporations
   {
       public int Employee_Id { get; set; }
       public int Corporation_Id { get; set; }
       public int WorkTime { get; set; }
   }
   ```

И при попытке обратиться к сущности в цикле `foreach` получаю исключение:

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException" в
>   EntityFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: One or more validation errors were detected
>   during model generation:
>
> TableGenerator.EmployeeCorporations: : EntityType
>   'EmployeeCorporations' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.
>
> EmployeeCorporationses: EntityType: EntitySet 'EmployeeCorporationses'
>   is based on type 'EmployeeCorporations' that has no keys defined.

При добавлении атрибута `[Key]`

```
    class EmployeeCorporations
    {
        [Key]
        public int Employee_Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int Corporation_Id { get; set; }
        public int work_period { get; set; }
    }
```

исключение принимает вид:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в
>   EntityFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Unable to determine composite primary key
>   ordering for type 'TableGenerator.EmployeeCorporations'. Use the
>   ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or
>   the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387)
>   to specify an order for composite primary keys.

Собственно вопрос, как правильно добавить поле в связующую таблицу?

**UPD**

При использовании

```
class EmployeeCorporations
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Employee_Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Corporation_Id { get; set; }
    public int WorkTime { get; set; }

}
```

Получаю исключение

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в
>   EntityFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: The model backing the
>   'CorporationListContext' context has changed since the database was
>   created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: Попробуйте добавить [Key, Column(Order = 0)], [Key, Column(Order = 1)]

Comment: @VadimBondaruk Пробовал, получаю исключение о том, что изменился контекст.

Comment: По последнему, выполните миграцию. А вообще я считаю лучше иметь сурогатный первичный ключ в каждой таблице, ну т.е. добавить `public long Id {get;set}`

Comment: @4per Чем лучше? Еще и long хотите под это дело выделить, чем вас составные ключи не устраивают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Невозможно создать отношение многие-ко-многим с дополнительным полем в связующей таблице.

Отношение многие-ко-многим обрабатывается EF при помощи дополнительной таблицы, которой не соответствует класс в вашей модели. Попытка поменять таблицу в самой базе (через SSMS) приводит к ошибкам: EF понимает, что реальная структура базы не соответствует описанной в классе и отказывается с ней работать (подобное случается и при работе с миграциями).

Поэтому, в первую очередь: оставьте ваши попытки поковырять базу руками, если вы используете EF Code First, вы так ничего не добьётесь.

Если вам действительно нужно дополнительное -- замените многие-ко-многим на на два отношения один-ко-многим. Создайте три класса, опишите связи, которые вам нужны. Либо удалите базу и создайте заново, либо (это типовой способ) используйте миграции.

Подробнее тут:

- [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7050404/5752652)

Итого:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeCorporation> EmployeeCorporations { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeCorporations = new List<EmployeeCorporation>();
    }
}    

public class Corporation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeCorporation> EmployeeCorporations { get; set; }

    public Corporation()
    {
        EmployeeCorporations = new List<EmployeeCorporation>();
    }
}

public class EmployeeCorporation
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CorporationId { get; set; }

    public Employee Corporation { get; set; }

    public int WorkTime { get; set; }
}
```